# Using CASE or IF Statement in Power BI

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, case, dax

I want to get a percentage of White people separate while the rest of the races will be People of color in a project am currently working in. Please I need help how to write the DAX either using CASE or IF statement.

I used SWITCH and it gave error

```
Race_Ethnicity = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "White or European", "White or European",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Black or African", "Black or African",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Hispanic or Latinx", "Hispanic or Latinx",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Prefer not to answer", "Prefer not to answer",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "South Asian", "South Asian",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "East Asian", "East Asian",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Middle Eastern", "Middle Eastern",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Southeast Asian", "Southeast Asian",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Pacific Islander", "Pacific Islander",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Indigenous","Indigenous",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "Other, please specify:", "Other, please specify:",
    'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = ".*(;).*", "Mixed Race or Ethnicity",
)
```

I am expecting to have the percentage of White or European and the percentage of People of color

Comment: While I have answered your question, I feel that the title of this question could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

When doing something akin to `SUMIF` in Power BI, we need to invoke `CALCULATE`. This function allows you to set filters that should be followed for parts of the calculation wrapped in `CALCULATE`.

Here are two measures. One for percentage of whites/europeans:

```
WOE % = 
VAR _count = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( 'Contact' ) , 
        'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] = "White or European"
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        _count , 
        COUNTROWS ( 'Contact' )
    )
```

And one for the opposite:

```
POC % = 
VAR _count = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( 'Contact' ) , 
        'Contact'[race_and_ethnicity] <> "White or European"
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        _count , 
        COUNTROWS ( 'Contact' )
    )
```